# Selenium and Python - browser keeps going back to initial page instead of staying on new page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to fill out this page: https://cityoflapcp.ezlinksgolf.com/index.html#/preSearch by selecting the date, number of players, location, and then clicking submit. The code I have below is able to do all of these things, but after clicking the submit button, it opens up the next URL briefly, but immediately goes back to the original page (almost like a refresh since all the fields that I filled out are reset). How do I get Selenium to stay on the new page?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://cityoflapcp.ezlinksgolf.com/index.html#/preSearch")

driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "preSearch-calendar-input").clear() 
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "preSearch-calendar-input").send_keys(date_of_play) # for some reason can't do clear and send keys in one line
Select(driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pc')).select_by_visible_text(num_players)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@value='6171']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@type='submit']").click()
time.sleep(10) # to keep the browser open for testing/debugging
```

I've tried using ActionChains to ctr+click the submit button to try opening a new tab instead of using the same tab, but no new tab is opened and the current tab resets back to the original driver.get() page. I've tried different ways of pausing the script (time.sleep(), input(), etc.), but same result.

Comment: Maybe you're getting detected? Did you try using [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) or undetected-chromedriver?

Comment: I tried using undetected-chromedriver and same problem

Comment: I don't think the problem is with detection since if it was, it wouldn't let me do anything but I am able to use the browser to a certain point

Comment: Mhh yeah but some sites use unexpected behaviour, to make the attacker think they didn't get detected: )